# Big-O proof showing that t(n) is O(1)

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science, proof-explanation

Let t(n) = $\sqrt{n^2+100n} - n$

Show that $t(n)$ is $O(1).$

I tried solving this using the formal definition of O( ) but am not getting anywhere. Quite confused on how to tackle this question.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n^2+100 n} - n & = (\sqrt{n^2+100 n} - n) \frac{\sqrt{n^2+100 n} + n}{\sqrt{n^2+100 n} + n} \\
 & = \frac{n^2+100 n-n^2}{\sqrt{n^2+100 n} + n} \\
& = \frac{100}{\sqrt{1+\frac{100}{n}} + 1} \quad \to \quad \frac{100}{2} = 50
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Ah I think I got it! Just wondering, how did you get to $100/2$ though?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{100}{n} = 0$ so what's left is $\frac{100}{\sqrt 1 + 1}$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for confirming my thoughts! However, is there a statement that I can say to reason why I take the limit n -> infinity?

Comment: For any function $f(n)$ if the (finite) limit exists $lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = L \lt \infty$ then $f(n) = \mathcal{O}(1)$.