# Why $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n^2+100n} - n=50$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n^2+100n} - n=50$$

Why is it $50$? I'm unsure how to solve this.

Is there some transformation to apply first? How do you know?

Comment: How do you know to do that / why

Comment: Answered yesterday at: [Big-O proof showing that t(n) is O(1)](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1972105/291201).

Comment: You will know by searching the hundreds (yes, literally!) of similar question on this site. For example, like this: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blimits%5D+sqrt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sqrt{n^2+100n} - n = \frac{(\sqrt{n^2+100n} - n)(\sqrt{n^2+100n} + n)}{(\sqrt{n^2+100n} + n)} = \frac{100n}{(\sqrt{n^2+100n} + n)}= \frac{100n}{n(\sqrt{1 + \frac{100}{n}} + 1)} = \frac{100}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{100}{n}} + 1} \longrightarrow\frac{100}{\sqrt{1} + 1} = 50$$

Comment: How do you know to do that / why

Comment: nice question, this gives you order $n$ in numerator and denominator.

Comment: @KaLiMa basically subtraction can be a huge pain, but addition is usually easier. Multiplication by the conjugate helps to rationalize then (now) numerator, while the denominator will be addition, which is easier to work with. But really, it's just a trick. Remember it, and look for a chance to use it in the future. That's how a lot of "math problems" get solved!

Answer (score 4):

We should complete the square. Note that we have 
$$\sqrt{n^2 + 100 n} - n = \sqrt{ (n+ 50)^2 - 2500} - n$$

Then as $n \to \infty$ we have $\sqrt{(n+50)^2 - 2500} \sim \sqrt{(n+50)^2} = n + 50$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how it approaches 50 algebraically, you can do this.

$\sqrt {n^2 +100n} - n = a$

$ n^2+100n = (a + n)^2$

$n^2 + 100n = a^2 + 2an + n^2$

$100n-2an = a^2$

$n = \frac{a^2}{100-2a}$

You can see how fast it converges by plugging in *a* values.

Taking the limit of the right hand side as *a* -> 50 will show *n* -> $\infty$

Comment: Wouldn't you want to solve for $a$ in that last step and look at the behavior as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @MikePierce His approach assumes you already know the limit